# Rails Bootstrap Forms : method gone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using the following gem:
https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms

Its installed by Bundler. I added the require statement in my application.css.
Yet, when I call the bootstrap_form_tag in my view, I get a **NoMethodError**

```
Undefined method `bootstrap_form_tag'
```

I am using Rails 4.1.6 - and I know the code is fine (its working on another app). How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be conflicting gems. I uninstalled the gem, reinstalled.